# Visual Studio 2022 Add DLL Reference

Tags: c#

on a WindowsForm project attemping to add a Reference to libwebp_x86.dll (present in the project folder), I get error "Cannot add a reference to libwebp_x86.dll

I took as reference
https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2022/08/29/c-convert-webp-to-jpeg-in-net/

compliant project works, if I delete from the references the dlls and try again to insert them, I still get error "Cannot add reference.."

It can't be a corrupted DLL problem, it wouldn't work even on Jose M.'s pogetto. Piñeiro

[image]

Comment: That not an assembly so you can't simply reference it. The link you provided talks about a WebPWrapper you need alongside the lib** dlls. If thats an assembly you need to reference that assembly.

Comment: The WebWrapper is a C# source that is added to the project

Comment: Then just throw the other dlls in the output folder.

Comment: The WebWrapper is a C# source that is added to the project ; call libwebp_x86.dll [DllImport("libwebp_x86.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "WebPConfigInitInternal")]

Comment: That's however a native import you don't reference, not a C# assembly.